# Writing basic Angular filters that allow toggling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering

I'm learning Angular and JS but I'm having trouble coming up with a filter function that allows filtering on/off (toggling) objects via buttons.

So given something like `ng-repeat="o in objects | filter:objectsFilter"`

Where an object looks like:

`{'id':1, 'name':'foo', 'property1':'bar', 'property2': 23, ...'}`

We have some buttons that act like checkboxes to filter our result set down:

```
<button ng-click="objectsFilter('property1', '=', 'bar')">Bar</button>
<button ng-click="objectsFilter('property1', '=', 'baz')">Baz</button>
<button ng-click="objectsFilter('property2', '>', 22)">Greater than 22</button>
<button ng-click="objectsFilter()">Clear All</button>
...
```

Where `objectsFilter([property], [comparison operator], [value])`. I don't know if this is the right approach (I've adopted it from Laravel's query builder). Please feel free to change it to suit the solution.

**The Problem**

How would I make the filters toggleable and stackable?

Toggleable: If the same property, comparison operator and value is already being filtered, remove that filter.

Stackable: Pretty self-explanatory, allows multiple filters at once.

So far all I got is a static filter:

```
 $scope.objectsFilter = function(object)
    {
        return object.property1 == 'bar'; // filters for property1: bar only.
    };
```

I don't know what approach I should take (other than a bunch of if statements) but I do have a feeling that with Angular it's more easy than it looks. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you want is something like this:

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-repeat="o in objects | objectsFilter:'value':'>':30">{{o.value}}</div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  console.log('app loaded');
  $scope.objects = [{value:10},{value:20},{value:30},{value:40},{value:50},{value:60},{value:70}];
});

app.filter('objectsFilter', function() {
  return function(object, property, comparator, expected) {
    var filteredObject = [],
        filtered = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    switch(comparator) {
      case '=':
        filtered = !(object[i][property] === expected);
        break;
      case '<':
        filtered = !(object[i][property] < expected);
        break;
      case '>':
        filtered = !(object[i][property] > expected);
        break;
      default:
        filtered = false;
    }
      if (!filtered) {
        filteredObject.push(object[i]);
      }
    }
    return filteredObject;
  };
});
```

working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wawyed/6C27r/1/)